# JForg Artifactory 7.x behind nginx 401 issue

Tags: nginx, artifactory

Everything is OK when visit `http://<ArtifactoryServerIp>:8082` directly. Then create a server config (following the [official example](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+NGINX)) in Nginx:

```
server{
# ...
    location / {
        # ...
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        # ...
    }
# ...

}
```

And visit `http://<ArtifactoryServerIp>`, sign in with account admin, and go to `Identity and Access` > `Users`, click `admin`. It will redirect to login page. Because there is a 401 error in browser console:

```
http://<ArtifactoryServerIp>/ui/api/v1/ui/userApiKey/admin?$no_spinner=true
```

But other requests are all OK, such as:

```
http://<ArtifactoryServerIp>/ui/api/v1/ui/users/admin
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be related to certain rewrites in Artifactory. I would recommend generating the reverse proxy configuration directly from Artifactory or you can refer to this [KB article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-recommended-nginx-reverse-proxy-configuration-for-artifactory-7-x-and-above/) on recommended reverse proxy configs for Nginx.

Comment: It looks same with https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+NGINX but the port of `/artifactory/` proxy_pass.